# Paperclip Gem Fails to convert PNG files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm getting errors when trying to upload PNG files. They fail during the size conversion (JPGs of the same image work).

```
[paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170214-36543-9hpxwk.png to /var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/d37e49548cb311938fd7b9a4fad0ba5920170214-36543-1ohpjiw.png
[paperclip] Trying to link /var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/d37e49548cb311938fd7b9a4fad0ba5920170214-36543-1ohpjiw.png to /var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/3ba1b91e6e962230b9633ff816bc1a9120170214-36543-3t80t8.png
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/3ba1b91e6e962230b9633ff816bc1a9120170214-36543-3t80t8.png'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/d37e49548cb311938fd7b9a4fad0ba5920170214-36543-1ohpjiw.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/d37e49548cb311938fd7b9a4fad0ba5920170214-36543-1ohpjiw.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/d37e49548cb311938fd7b9a4fad0ba5920170214-36543-1ohpjiw.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x40" -crop "40x40+10+0" +repage -quality -95 -strip '/var/folders/pm/62y5jbv57ln82b3fr6cs5wbh0000gn/T/b7e52de8a8f1bb07d5db075edbe15b4c20170214-36543-1ui2yuo'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 481ms (ActiveRecord: 21.4ms)
```

So, you can see it's failing immediately as it tries to convert. In my model:

```
  has_attached_file :picture,
                    styles: {tiny: ["40x40#", :jpg], square_thumb: "100x100#", thumb: "100x100>", square: "300x300#", medium: "300x300>", large: "600x600>", xlarge: '1000x1000>'},
                    convert_options: {thumb: "-quality 95 -strip", medium: "-quality 95 -strip", tiny: "-quality -95 -strip", square_thumb:"-quality -95 -strip", square:"-quality -95 -strip"  },
                    url: "/system/:class/:id/headshot_:hash.:extension",
                    hash_secret: ENV['DOC_SECRET']

  validates_attachment :picture, presence: true,
                       content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage/ },
                       size: { less_than: 3.megabytes }
```

Note, I changed the `tiny` conversion to convert the PNG to JPG as I was trying to debug and now, whenever I upload a PNG the `tiny` conversion works and the next fails.

This is happening in both production and development, so either I've set something wrong or there's a Paperclip issue. I'm not inclined to believe it's an ImageMagick problem, unless both I and Heroku (production server) have the same problem. Incidentally, forcing a convert to PNG -- `["40X40#, :png]` also fails.

I suppose I can just force every image to be converted to JPG, and for this application that's not much of a problem but I'd rather figure out the root issue and fix that.

Another note, I also tried `tiny: "40x40>"` and that failed, too. The only way I can get the conversion to work is to force a format change to something that is not PNG. I'm using Paperclip version 5.1.0

UPDATE:
Removing `tiny: "-quality -95 -strip",` allows the conversion to work -- so the problem is in there somewhere. I have to run out but my guess is the quality conversion doesn't apply to PNG files.